# Unable to load a pre trained weight of CycleGAN and get accurate results

Tags: python, pytorch

I have trained a cycleGAN for denoising image and have a .pth model. However when I try to load the model and test an image i am not getting a accurate denoised image. But when I try to run it on jupyternotebook through script which is mentioned below it works:

"%run pytorch-CycleGAN-and-pix2pix/test.py 
--dataroot testB/ 
--name cgan_date_snippet --model test --no_dropout --num_test 10"

But when i try to create a class outof it and test it it's not working below is the code for that

```
import torch
    from options.base_options import BaseOptions
    from models.networks import define_G

    # opt = BaseOptions()

    # generator = define_G(input_nc=3, output_nc=3, ngf=64,
    #                      netG='resnet_9blocks', norm='instance', use_dropout='store_true')
    # generator = define_G(input_nc=3, output_nc=3, ngf=64, netG='unet_256', norm='batch', use_dropout='store_true',init_type='normal',init_gain=0.02)
    generator = define_G(input_nc=3, output_nc=3, ngf=64, netG='resnet_9blocks', norm='instance', use_dropout=False)


# Load the pre-trained weights from a saved checkpoint
generator_checkpoint_path = 'latest_net_G_B.pth'






checkpoint = torch.load(generator_checkpoint_path, map_location=torch.device('cuda'))


# Print the keys in the pre-trained model's state_dict to understand its structure
print(checkpoint.keys())

# Load the generator state_dict
generator.load_state_dict(checkpoint, strict=False)

# Set the model to evaluation mode (important if using dropout during training)
generator.eval()






from PIL import Image
from torchvision import transforms
from IPython.display import display


# Load your input image
input_image_path = 'nt6.jpg'
input_image = Image.open(input_image_path).convert('RGB')

# Resize the input image to the expected size
input_image = input_image.resize((512, 512))

# Convert the input image to a PyTorch tensor
input_tensor = transforms.ToTensor()(input_image).unsqueeze(0)  # Add batch dimension

# Move the input tensor to the GPU if available
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    input_tensor = input_tensor.to('cuda')

# Set the generator to evaluation mode (if not already)
generator.eval()

# Move the generator to the same device as the input tensor
generator = generator.to(input_tensor.device)

# Generate the output image
with torch.no_grad():
    output_tensor = generator(input_tensor)

# Move the output tensor to the CPU if necessary
output_tensor = output_tensor.cuda()

# Convert the output tensor to a PIL image
output_image = transforms.ToPILImage()(output_tensor.squeeze(0))

# Display the generated image
display(output_image)

# Save the generated image
output_image.save('image2.jpg')
```

Please help out it would be deeply apprieated.

Help out which is very much crutial